# Setting full permission for a file in android

Tags: android, file

I am using the following code to set the full permission for a file in android.
But it is not working. I am not able to find the reason of that. Please help on this.

```
File mypath=new File(directory, filename+ ".png");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 " + mypath); 
System.out.println("FileExecute " + mypath.canExecute());
System.out.println("FileRead " + mypath.canRead());
System.out.println("FileWrite " + mypath.canWrite());
System.out.println("FileExists " + mypath.exists());
System.out.println("FileisFile " + mypath.isFile());
```

I am getting every output as 'false'. Is there any other method to set the full permission.

Comment: System.out.println("FileisFile " + mypath.isFile()); Please note that it is also giving false. But the directory and file is right

Comment: Check Your file in file explorer ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `exists()` output is false it means that file dosn't exists so you should first create it by call to `mypath.createNewFile()`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if (file.exists())
{
    file.setExecutable(boolean);
    file.setReadable(boolean);
    file.setWritable(boolean);
}
```